# Custom xsl files for content query web part in location other than Style library?

Tags: 2010, content-query-web-part

Can we put our custom xsl files for CBQ in a location other than Style Library (in Layouts directory in 14 hive for instance)?

Trying to do so is giving me the following error : "The web part references an untrusted XSL file. Only XSL files contained in this site's Style Library may be referenced."

Is there any way to overcome this?

By the way I am trying this in SP2010

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6975151/sharepoint-content-query-webpart-untrusted-xsl-file

Loks like you have same issue.

Answer (score 1):

Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6975151/sharepoint-content-query-webpart-untrusted-xsl-file

Loks like you have same issue. The file must belong to your site collection in which cqwp exist.

Comment: What I really need is to know if there is a way to overcome this limitation.

Comment: Can you explain how this limits you?

Answer (score 0):

I don't recommend you to place those custom xsl files (or any other style resources) in the layouts directory. You're losing the advantage of versioning, check-in-check-out, ... .